# Setting a default action when declining an invitation in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to get rid of this dialog box popping-up every time I decline calender invitations in Outlook 2007:

[image: outlook calendar dialog]

There doesn't seem to be a "Choose this action and never ask me again" option.

Where is the setting to set a choice as the automatic default action for future pop-ups?

Answer (score 1):

Default control of how meetings requests are responded can only be controlled by the meeting creator. They can indicate whether they want a response or not, but you as the recipient have to decide on a case-by-case basis. I can't find an MS-based page with a formal answer to the question, but the link below indicates that you can't do what you want.

http://oit.utk.edu/exchange/faq/faq_outlook_2007_calendar.php#Outlook_2007_357.